# Android Bundle App Signature different between bundle, APK and appstore

Tags: android, android-studio

For my android app, i have been doing an ./gradlew bundleRelease and then uploading it to playstore.

However i realized that if i were to assembleRelease for an APK, the signature generated from the APK is different from the one eventually approved in playstore. Even worse, when the bundle is uploaded onto another store (Huawei appgallery) the signature changed too! As a result, my wechat login fails because of the authentication check vs the signature.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Check if google play signing uses your key to actually sign the app or if they use an own key. Afaik, it is now the default setting that google will generate a key for you.

Comment: That means i am stuck with different signatures for different stores? hmm.